# How to access class parameters?

Tags: scala

According the book *Programming in Scala*, page 304

```
class Queue[T] private (leading: List[T], trailing: List[T]){
  private def mirror =
    if(leading.isEmpty) new Queue(trailing.reverse, Nil)
    else this
  def head = mirror.leading.head
  def tail = {
    val q = mirror
    new Queue(q.leading.tail, q.trailing)
  }
  def append[T](x: T)={
    new Queue(leading, x::trailing)
  }
}
```

I get the following errors

```
Error:value leading is not a member of Queue[T]
def head = mirror.leading.head
```

Same error for `trailing`.
`mirror` is an object of the class `Queue` right? Why can't it access it's class parameters?

Comment: use val or var ```class Queue[T] private (val leading: List[T], val trailing: List[T])``` to create member fields, without val or var, leading is a constructor parameter not visible outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed `leading` and `trailing` are members of `Queue` class but they are private by default. To make them public add `val` annotation:

Before:

```
scala> class Queue[T] private (leading: List[T], trailing: List[T]){
     |   private def mirror =
     |     if(leading.isEmpty) new Queue(trailing.reverse, Nil)
     |     else this
     |   def head = mirror.leading.head
     |   def tail = {
     |     val q = mirror
     |     new Queue(q.leading.tail, q.trailing)
     |   }
     |   def append[T](x: T)={
     |     new Queue(leading, x::trailing)
     |   }
     | }
<console>:15: error: value leading is not a member of Queue[T]
         def head = mirror.leading.head
                           ^
<console>:18: error: value leading is not a member of Queue[T]
           new Queue(q.leading.tail, q.trailing)
                       ^
<console>:18: error: value trailing is not a member of Queue[T]
           new Queue(q.leading.tail, q.trailing)
                                       ^
```

After:

```
scala> class Queue[T] private (val leading: List[T], val trailing: List[T]){
     |   private def mirror =
     |     if(leading.isEmpty) new Queue(trailing.reverse, Nil)
     |     else this
     |   def head = mirror.leading.head
     |   def tail = {
     |     val q = mirror
     |     new Queue(q.leading.tail, q.trailing)
     |   }
     |   def append[T](x: T)={
     |     new Queue(leading, x::trailing)
     |   }
     | }
defined class Queue
```

You can read about constructors and getters in detail [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html). Relevant point is:

> Parameters without `val` or `var` are private values, visible only within
>   the class.